# Custom text and dropdown button options in OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I've recently tried the newest version of WinZip and saw the text and options in the "Zip" file dialog...
How can I do this in C#?
By the way, if you haven't figured it out yet... I am talking about the Vista/7 Open File Dialog.
I would rather have code than a "you take [x] line(s) of code from [this article] to do [this] and figure out the rest yourself". If I could, I would have done that.

Comment: That's done with the IFileDialogCustomize COM interface.  Not impossible but very incompatible with the last two lines in your question.

Comment: @Hans Passant Indeed... How would I implement it?

Comment: The Windows API code pack appears to wrap this interface.  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.Controls namespace.  Example is here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSShellCommonFileDialog-dd199163/sourcecode?fileId=20570&pathId=537743262 and you figure out the rest yourself.

Comment: @Hans Passant Sorry for late answer! I downloaded the sample and I am going to look at it when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went all Rambo on this and I used the win32 API functions to customize the dialog.
Works only when my app runs elevated on Windows Vista or 7.

(Sorry for answering so late, but I forgot about this question...)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no significant customization can be performed with the default open file dialogue. You'll have to create your own. This isn't too bad, since you can use a file browser control to do most of the complex stuff.

---

Edit: Apparently "file browser control" came from my imagination and not my memory. I can't find a standard Microsoft-issue file browser control. So your options are:

- Download a third-party file browser control and integrate that into your dialogue.
- (more likely) - approach your design problem from a different angle. What exactly does the Winzip dialogue do, and why do you want to replicate it?

Comment: A file browser control? Is there even a built-in one or do I have to write my own? :C

Comment: I have actually already tried this. It breaks consistency with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IFileDialogCustomize interface to achieve the customization, but this can be very cumbersome and time-consuming and inflexible.

Another alternative is to use third party controls like [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) which are controls for putting Windows Explorer like file/folder browsing in your own forms.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developers of Shell MegaPack.